# How do i create ruby variable properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I am using ruby on rails.

I need a variable, @slideshow, to have the properties @slideshow.link, @slideshow.name, and @slideshow.description

I have a model/table GenPackage that has the columns image_link, image_name, image_description

I can use

```
@slideshow = GenPackage.all
```

But this will give me a variable with the properties of @slideshow.image_link, @slideshow.image_name, and @slideshow.image_description

How can I get it so that the properties are named without the "image_"?

Comment: Can you modify or patch `GenPackage`?

Answer (score 2):

If you can change `GenPackage`, use [`alias_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute):

> **alias_attribute(new_name, old_name)**
>
> Allows you to make aliases for attributes, which includes getter, setter, and query methods.

Something like this:

```
class GenPackage < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :link, :image_link
  alias_attribute :name, :image_name
  alias_attribute :description, :image_description
end
```

That will let you use `link`, `name`, and `description` everywhere (getters, setters, queries, forms, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `method_missing`:

```
class GenPackage
  def image_link
    puts 'image_link'
  end
  def image_name
    puts 'image_name'
  end
  def method_missing (method_name, *args, &block)
    send(('image_'+method_name.to_s).to_sym, *args, &block)
  end
end

g=GenPackage.new
g.link
#=> image_link
g.name
#=> image_name
```